# "Not in outer par mode" error when using Algorithm inside minipage

Tags: minipage, algorithms

I am trying to place a figure and an algorithm side-by-side using minipage. Hee is the code for the algorithm part. However, I am getting an error `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` on the line `\KwData`. If I delete it, I am getting the error on the next line `\Input`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionof{algocf}{CAPTION}
\label{alg:alg2}
\begin{algorithm}
\KwData{$ . . .$}
\Input{$ . . . $}
\eIf{$ condition $}{
        $ . . . .  $
    }{
        $ . . . . $
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which algorithm-related packages you load.

Comment: @Mico I have edited the question. Please check

Comment: put a bit more effort in your question and show a compilable document which can actually be used to test your problem.

Comment: IIRC, algorithm2e is a float, and you can't put floats inside minipages.  You can switch to a package (like algorithms) which separates the float and \hbox evironments.  You could also use paracol, which does allows floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `H` specifier as mentioned in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.58\textwidth}
\captionof{algocf}{CAPTION}
\label{alg:alg2}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{$ . . .$}
\Input{$ . . . $}
\eIf{$ condition $}{
        $ . . . .  $
    }{
        $ . . . . $
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}
\captionof{algocf}{CAPTION}
\label{alg:alg2-bis}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{$ . . .$}
\Input{$ . . . $}
\eIf{$ condition $}{
        $ . . . .  $
    }{
        $ . . . . $
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]